Using CORS in cloud functions
I have a question about CORS and its usage and syntax, in Google Cloud Functions.
Here is some working code I have in cloud functions :
import {onRequest} from "firebase-functions/v2/https";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import {Reference} from "firebase-admin/database";
import {DataSnapshot} from "firebase-admin/database";

.....

exports.myCloudFunction = onRequest({cors: ["*"]}, (req, res) => {
  ... useful funtion code, but irrelevant for the question ...
}); /* End of myCloudFuntion */

Though it is functionally working, I have the feeling I am not doing it right in terms of security.
Indeed I want the function above to be callable only from my site and from nowhere else.
My site being: https://example.mygreatsite.net
How should I change the code in the function (myCloudFuntion) to reach that goal ?

CORS doesn't stop an HTTP endpoint from being called "from nowhere else".  It just stops conforming web browsers from completing an HTTP request/response cycle from pages loaded from specific sites.  A non-conforming browser or any other HTTP client can do whatever it wants.  CORS does not at all improve security. It just prevents hapless end users from participating in attacks.

Yes, in fact of security you are allowing requests from everywhere at the moment by
cors:["*"]

this is okay for testing purposes but lacks security.
To only allow calls from your site, replace * with your url, for example
cors:["https://example.mygreatsite.net"]


To expand on this, you should not hardcode the URL. You should set a environment variable and set the allowed domains based on the environment. For example, the environment variable process.env.CORS could be * in DEV, but https://example.mygreatsite.net in PROD.

I have a file called .env where I indeed have some environment variables.
But I am not totally confident about this being considered as DEV or PROD.

@Mhyt0z. I have tried to change the code as indicated. But I can still call the function by typing its URL in the address bar of my browser. Is that how it is supposed to be ?
I expected not to be able to call it that way but only from https://example.mygreatsite.net.

@Michel what you are seeing is the expected behavior when using cors.
It only allows requests from the specified url. Since it's not a request coming from a url, but rather a request made directly without a url, cors allows it.
If you want to completely block requests that are coming from a different url you could use something like firebase authentication to authenticate each request, tho i am not that familiar with this.
